# Very slow IOPS on Google Cloud SSD. Why?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have the following server on Google Cloud: 8vCPU, 16GB memory with 50GB SSD system disk and 1024 GB SSD for data.

But it's very slow:

```
  read : io=3071.7MB, bw=4503.4KB/s, iops=1125, runt=698463msec
  write: io=1024.4MB, bw=1501.8KB/s, iops=375, runt=698463msec
```

I have only 1125iops on the 1TB SSD disk. Any idea why it is slow slow? I've got ~23.000 iops on Rackspace with similar specs...

Comment: I'm wondering if this may be better suited for Super User, [under the same tag](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform).

Comment: FYI I ran a test (https://www.binarylane.com.au/support/solutions/articles/1000055889-how-to-benchmark-disk-i-o) against the same specs and saw 10x iops for both read and write. Any chance you tested against Standard PD rather than SSD?